# Unity - NavMeshComponets not completely implemented in Unity 5.6

Tags: unity-game-engine, components, navmesh

I have a question about the new NavMesh in Unity 5.6. I am not able to find any of the mentioned in the 5.6 release notes new Nav Mesh components (navMesh Surface, (Volume) Modifier).

I do not really know how to easily get them. I have already downloaded the files at: https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/NavMeshComponents and I am planning to implement them in my project. I think is weird that you have to manually download them from GitHub, when they mentioned them in the Unity 5.6 release notes.

Do you know an easier way to use them in Unity?

Friendly Greetings, Quinten

Comment: @Tom Fuller, where you able to see the enters in edit mode? The enters are exactly how I placed them in Word. (They got deleted in the posting process, somehow)

Comment: Stack overflow has different formatting to word, you can have a maximum gap of one line, but it will only start a new line if there is one new line in-between, you can see what the post will look like while you're creating it.